# Android App Lags on lollipop and below version mostly on Oppo, Vivo and MI, working fine on Emulator

Tags: android

Android App Lags on Lollipop and below version mostly on Oppo, Vivo, and MI, working fine on Emulator

My app is developed in Kotlin
The app is having following things in build.gradle

compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'

minSdkVersion  19
targetSdkVersion 27

multiDexEnabled true

I spend 5 days but have not got any solution, please help

Comment: Is your app "lagging" or is it crashing?? If it's crashing, you should try to debug it with these devices, maybe there must be some permission missing. You can check out this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for various reasons of the same

Comment: You should consider running lint tests, improving your code, support Async Tasks for tasks that takw time, using tools like LeakCanary to check for memory leaks and clearing unused data from the app storage. Also check if you probably missed out detaching listeners in your onPause() or onStop() callbacks that were recommended while you were using third party libraries. Also use Android Profiler to check how much memory is being used.